# DeprecationWarning in sklearn MiniBatchKMeans

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
vectors = model.syn0

n_clusters_kmeans = 20 # more for visualization 100 better for clustering

min_kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=n_clusters_kmeans, n_init=10)
min_kmeans.fit(vectors)

X_reduced = TruncatedSVD(n_components=50,  random_state=0).fit_transform(vectors)
X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=40, verbose=2).fit_transform(X_reduced)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.axes(frameon=False)
plt.setp(ax, xticks=(), yticks=())
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, bottom=0.0, right=1.0, top=0.9,     wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)
plt.scatter(X_embedded[:, 0], X_embedded[:, 1], c=None, marker="x")
plt.show()
```

I want to plot vectors. I am using sklearn.cluster MiniBatchKMeans. 
Above code is giving me following deprecation error:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py:1328: DeprecationWarning: This function is deprecated. Please call randint(0, 99 + 1) instead
>     0, n_samples - 1, self.batch_size)

Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Try to ignore the warning and see if the code still works as desired. You can do so by :                                                                                     `import warnings` 
`warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)`

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue and a fix has already been merged for this. Please refer to [gh:scikit-learn#6863](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6863).

Statistically the next release should be released around Oct. 2016. Till then following are the options:

--> **Suppress** as mentioned in [frist's answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38261393/2670370)

```
import warnings
....
min_kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(...)
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
    min_kmeans.fit(vectors)
# Rest part of the code
```

--> **Install** scikit-learn from master:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

Answer (score 3):

### Temporarily Suppressing Warnings

The best option to suppress this warning has been described in python's documentation for the [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings) module.

In this case you can just wrap the clusterizer fitting method using *with* statement like this:

```
import warnings
....
min_kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(...)
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    min_kmeans.fit(vectors)
# Rest part of the code
```